# Show custom values on zgraph

Tags: asp.net, zedgraph

[image: I have plotted a graph using zedgraph library as shown in figure.On x axis zedgraph automatically plotting values between range in our case 1 to 20 its not showing intermediate values i.e. 1,2,3,4....20 I want show point 1,2,3,4,5...20 as well.How can I do that??]

I have plotted a graph using zedgraph library as shown in figure.On x axis zedgraph automatically plotting values between range in our case 1 to 20 its not showing intermediate values i.e. 1,2,3,4....20 I want show point 1,2,3,4,5...20 as well.How can I do that??

Answer (score 0):

> MajorStep
>   Gets or sets the scale step size for this Scale (the increment between labeled axis values).

http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/default.html

See Scale Class, scroll down to MajorStep

Or http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/ZedGraph/ZedGraph/Scale/P/MajorStep

```
        .GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStep = 1;
        .GraphPane.XAxis.Scale.MajorStepAuto = false;  // Not needed, see documentation.
```